# Rails routes: Can object ids be separated by non-backslash strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to do the following:

```
/products/compare/:product_a_id--vs--:product_b_id
```

Is this possible?

Comment: no, it's not possible.  what's wrong with a forward slash?

Comment: I think I figured it out Julie. Sometimes "vs" makes more sense than "/"

Comment: Not a very RESTful URL. Your URL should be something like `/products/:id/compare?other=:product_id`, or `/products/:id/compare/:other_product_id`

Comment: Sometimes SEO trumps RESTful. Seeing the "vs" in the URL is my goal. I agree with you though.

Comment: I might try something like `/products/:id/vs/:other_product_id`

Answer (score 0):

So, a little hacky, but here's my solution:

```
resources "products" do
  constraints( compare: /compare/ ) do
    constraints( lambda { |request| Product.find_by(slug: request.params["product_a"]) } ) do
      constraints( compare: /--vs--/ ) do
        constraints( lambda { |request| Product.find_by(slug: request.params["product_b"]) } ) do
          collection do
            get 'compare/:product_a--vs--:product_b', to: 'products#compare', as: 'compare'
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rake routes:

```
rake routes | grep compare

compare_products GET       

/products/compare/:product_a--vs--:product_b(.:format)       products#compare
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "id" however you like.

In the controller action, you can just split it based on the string

```
def compare
  product_a_id, product_b_id = params[:id].split('--vs--')
  ...
end
```

And in routes, throw on a constraint to ensure the `--vs--` is there.

```
:constraints => { :id => /\d+--vs--\d+/ }
```